# jquery mobile with backbone.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I have the following module with backbone:

```
define(['backbone','jqm','text!modules/home/templates/home.html'],function(Backbone,jqm,templ){
    var homeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        layoutTemplate:_.template(templ),
        render: function(){
            $.mobile.changePage('asdf',{})
        }

    });
    return homeView;
});
```

Just trying to check if it works. But i always get the page with only text as "Loading" !
Here is the jqm-config file:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

        // Remove page from DOM when it's being replaced
        $('div[data-role="page"]').on('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
            $(event.currentTarget).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your router code?

Comment: well actually I want to load the page after this view is loaded. I want to trigger it this way only. All the changepage methods should behave more or like the render method of the view. This will somewhat maintain the backbone architecture.

Comment: In your 'mobileinit' code above you have turned off jqm routing. I have done something simlar. Basically, all my routing goes through backbone and there I initialize my view, render it, and then tell jqm to go there (changepage). It is very simlar to this: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/